# Access Util.logger from multiple classes

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I'm new to util.logging so this might seem a trivial question to some but anyway here goes..I'm using Java's Util.logger to log messages. I'm trying to declare a logger in a single class and accessing it from other classes for logging messages.

**Logger class**

```
package util;

import java.util.logging.*;

public class Logger {

public Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

 }
```

I'm trying to access this logger in other class as follows..

```
package mycode;

import util.Logger;

public class MYcode{

private void test(){
 LOGGER.fine("Sample message");
}
}
```

**Compilation Error message**..

```
error: cannot find symbol
[javac]LOGGER.fine("Sample message");
```

When I'm declaring logger in Mycode class then I'm not getting any error but when declaring it another class I'm getting an error. Any idea where I'm going wrong??

Comment: `LOGGER` is not static here so you can't call it that way. If it were you'd either need to do a static import of `util.Logger.LOGGER` (`import static ...`) or access it via `Logger.LOGGER`.

Comment: ...move on to Log4J....

Answer (score 0):

Just keep using in all classes needing the logger the same line:

```
public Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
```

This way you are creating many references to one instance of logger identified by the global name.

Comment: I need to use the above line only once to simplify the code..any idea how to do it?

Comment: make `LOGGER` `static` and `final` and you can use it by calling `Logger.LOGGER.fine("msg")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your 'LOGGER' is NOT static, so you are NOT able to access.

**Logger class:**

```
package util;

import java.util.logging.*;

public class Logger {

public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

 }
```

**Accessing logger in other class:**

```
package mycode;

        import util.Logger;

        public class MYcode{

        public void test(){
         LOGGER.fine("Sample message");

        }    
    }
```

Comment: By mistake I made test method public in my question.It's actually private, I've edited my question accordingly..will your answer work then also??